# ASP.NET MVC: Multiple submit buttons using Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a page that has a next button and previous button that switches the image displayed.

For that purpose I created an `Ajax.BeginForm` and inserted into it, an image and two submit buttons.

Can I (should I) have multiple submit buttons inside an `Ajax.BeginForm`?

How would the controller handle each submit separately?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this,

**View**

```
@model TwoModelInSinglePageModel.RegisterModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DYmanicControllerPage", "Test", FormMethod.Post,null, new { id = "frmSignUp" }))
{ 
  <div>
                <input type="hidden" id="" name="hidden2" id="hdasd" />
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hidden1)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address)
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNo)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNo)
            </div>

 <input type="submit" value="Save"  id="btnSave" name="ButtonType"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Next"  id="btnNext" name="ButtonType" />


}
```

**Controller**

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DYmanicControllerPage(RegisterModel model,  string ButtonType)
        {
        if(ButtonType == "Next")
        {
            // Do Next Here
        }
        if (ButtonType == "Save")
        {
            //Do save here
        }
        return JavaScript("REturn anything()");

        }
```

Comment: The model which I get in this action does not hold the values from the page. is that natural?

Comment: @kroiz sorry i don't understand what are you try to say.Can you post some code so i can help you.

Comment: Thanks but this is not the place for this, I will start a new question. just tell me this: in the above action "DYmanicControllerPage", the model "RegisterModel model", does it supposed to have the data from the form like name, address and phoneno?

Comment: @kroiz Yes you can get data in `egisterModel model` using this in your view page  `@model TwoModelInSinglePageModel.RegisterModel`. i just update my post.

Comment: How would this work if you have a picture in your button or the buttons are translated?

Comment: @Rogier21 i don't understand button are translated? could you more specific what is your requirement.

Comment: Nowadays we use buttons like this: <button class="btn blue" type="submit" data-submit="0">Volgende <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>. What kind of ugly switch would you have to make, very error prone.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend that you have two buttons and then depending on what button was clicked you could set the action on the form:

**Razor**

```
$(function (){
    $("#btn-prev").click(function() {
        $("#form").attr
                   (
                      "action",
                      "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new {area="Area" })", 
                   ).submit();
    });
    $("#btn-next").click(function() {
        $("#form").attr
                   (
                      "action",
                      "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new {area="Area" })", 
                   ).submit();
    });
});
```

I am using jQuery here to do this, but I think you can get the idea.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little about the action in the controller. should I have one action? If so how do I differentiate between previous and next? also what is the action url?  thanks.

Comment: The action is the url the form posts to. If you modify that on the fly you can change the location the form is going to post to. You only need to have one `Ajax.BeginForm`. It will output the `form` tag on the client which you can change via JavaScript.

Comment: Using the above, but I am unable to reach the action. Does it matter how I write the `Ajax.BeginForm`? Do I need a special signature for the action in the control?   I called `@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement/issue and tried both solutions here and they both work for me. I LIKE the idea of setting the action via jquery when clicking so I can keep my actions separate so they can be used by other views.

HOWEVER, I've found that when I do this while I debug, it posts TWICE and *BOTH* the OnSuccess and OnFailure are triggered. It only happens when debugging though. Keep this in mind when picking.

Comment: Just a note: It happens normally, not just when debugging. I had a txt file logging a timestamp every time my action was executed. Debugging or not, I got TWO lines written when I set the form's action via jquery.... but when the action was hard coded, it only wrote one line. Until I can figure out why, this may not be a safe method

Comment: Also... I found a lot of artciles about Ajax.Beginform double posting. They ALL had to do with people adding the unobtrusive javascript JS file twice by accident (once in a partial view and once in master layout). This was NOT the case for me. So I have no idea why this is happening. I will continue to look into it because I REALLY want the jquery method to work